# Redirect response from Flask with CGI doesn't redirect

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am having trouble with redirects. This code works fine on my local machine, but when I host it on a web server in cgi-bin, `redirect(url_for('hello_world'))` takes me to the redirect page,

> Redirecting...
>
> You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /~bsorsch/cgi-bin/one_shot_game.cgi/. If not click the link.

rather than actually redirecting. How can I correct this?

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/other')
def other():
    return redirect(url_for('hello_world'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <a href="{{ url_for('other') }}">Switch pages</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get a 301 from the redirect URL?

Comment: I believe I get a 302: >Status: 302 FOUND Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 279 Location: http://stanford.edu/~bsorsch/cgi-bin/one_shot_game.cgi/